# Qt-creator: my QMessageBox is not closing

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qmessagebox

I am using a `QMessageBox` to warn the user if he pressed Delete button by mistake. when the user press Ok button in the `QMessageBox`, a function is called to delete a row from `QTableView` (that is connected to a database). after the deletion, the QTableView should be refreshed and the new data (without the deleted row) should be shown.

now, when the user hits `Delete button`, the warning `QMessageBox` appears. then, when he presses Ok, the row is deleted from the `QTableView`. at this point I expect the `QMessageBox` to disappear, and the new refreshed version of the `QTableView` to be shown which is not happening !!. instead the `QMessageBox` appears again and the refresh has to be manually done (as I am just starting the application ) .. why is this happening ?

here is my code:

```
QMessageBox msg;
msg.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
msg.setText("Delete");
msg.setInformativeText("continue ?");
msg.setDetailedText("Delete permanently");
msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
msg.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);

int ret = msg.exec();
if(ret == 1024){
    msg.Close;
    deleteDataBaseRecord(); // connect to server and delete DB data which is then show the QTableView again
}
else {
    msg.Close;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have () on your Close calls... is this really C++ ?

Don't use the keywords (delete) as function names.

Also, don't use constants (1024) when there are names available.

Comment: 1- there is no any() in the Close, and yes it c++. 2- I put "Delete" for simplicity but it is called something else in the actual code. 3- I can't change the returned int, it is already defined as when you press OK you will get int 1024 and I am just using it

Answer (score 0):

You should call `msg.close()` (without the capital C) to close `msg` message box.

Additionally the return value of `QMessageBox::exec()` method can be `QMessageBox::Ok` if the OK button that was clicked. Actually, `QMessageBox::Close` (in your case `msg.Close`) can be one of those buttons.